# Cannot find JRI native library. Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path

Tags: java, r, eclipse, rjava

I've tried the method as in this website: "http://codophile.com/2015/04/15/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rjava/" followed instructions and ran in eclipse but get error:

> "Cannot find JRI native library!
>   Please make sure that the JRI native library is in a directory listed in java.library.path."

Later copied jri.dll from rjava library location to native jdk bin folder and again re-ran that, got the output fine!!!

Tried this method also:

`-Djava.library.path="C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rJava\jri\x64;C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.0\bin\x64";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin";"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin"`

in eclipse VM argument. Not getting the output untill the jri is copied to native java libary.

But I want some other method as copying the .dll file to jdk folder is not much that correct way. If there is any another good method of getting output please reply.

Comment: In the following part of the path `...\rJava\jri\x64;C:\Program Files\...` the semicolon must be surrounded by double quotes (instead `...\x64;C:\...` it must be `...\x64";"C:\...`). Otherwise the two directories are treated as one entry, as there are double quotes before the first one and after the second one.

Comment: I've done the suggested changes even also i'm getting same error JRI native library not found!! The only way is copying jri.dll from rjava to jdk native library path...!!! If possible can you tell the correct procedure from begining

Comment: In which directory is the file `jri.dll`?

Comment: C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\Documents\R\win-library\3.5\rJava\jri\x64 copied from here and pasted to C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin. Java used is jdk1.8.0_172 and jre1.8.0_172

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple check if there is not a typo in the directory names somewhere.

**Jri.java**

```
import java.io.File;

public class Jri {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] paths = System.getProperty("java.library.path").split(";");

        for (String path : paths) {
            File file = new File(path + "/jri.dll");
            System.out.printf("file: %s  exists: %s%n", file, file.exists());
        }
        // when the library was found in one of the locations
        // this call should not throw an exception
        System.loadLibrary("jri.dll");
    }
}
```

compile the source

```
java Jri.java
```

run it with the JVM property

```
java -Djava.library.path=[put here the directories] Jri
```

if the file is not found on any location check for typos.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this. Reconfigure path, increase

```
%R_HOME%\library\rJava\jri\i386;
%R_HOME%\bin\i386 these two paths.
```

Before using java proxy R, try to make the version uniform